# Meaning of the LLVM Optimization Levels

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, llvm

I recently started working with Clang/LLVM and would like to know if there is any particular documentation on what the -Ox optimization levels do?

I couldn't find much on the LLVM documentation page. Can someone share a few links?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Clang's command-line options documentation is indeed very poor, and in particular you are correct that there's almost no explanation of what the optimizations level do.

FreeBSD, however, does add a [man page with a useful summary](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=clang++&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE):

> `-O0 -O1 -O2 -Os -Oz -O3 -O4`
>              Specify which optimization level to use.  -O0 means "no
>          optimization": this level compiles the fastest and generates the
>          most debuggable code.  -O2 is a moderate level of optimization
>          which enables most optimizations.  -Os is like -O2 with extra
>          optimizations to reduce code size.  -Oz is like -Os (and thus -O2),
>          but reduces code size further.  -O3 is like -O2, except that it
>          enables optimizations that take longer to perform or that may
>          generate larger code (in an attempt to make the program run
>          faster).  On supported platforms, -O4 enables link-time
>          optimization; object files are stored in the LLVM bitcode file
>          format and whole program optimization is done at link time. -O1 is
>          somewhere between -O0 and -O2.

If you're looking to find the exact list of passes performed for each optimization, see this Stackoverflow question:

- [Clang optimization levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548023/clang-optimization-levels)