# Compile using clang optimisation passes/flags

Tags: clang, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-clang

I am trying to compile a program, using clang3.4, and the optimisation passes (or flags?!) I used, are ignored.

For example I am trying to compile and I pass the following options"
`-O1 -instcombine`

I get:

```
clang34: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-instcombine'
```

The list of all available optimisation passes of LLVM can be found [here](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html), and in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548023/clang-optimization-levels). Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: The only option that I found that it is not being ignore is `-fstrict-aliasing`, which is not listed in the 2 links I attached in the Q.

Answer (score 6):

These are LLVM optimization passes, not clang's. You cannot invoke LLVM optimization passes directly. However, you can emit LLVM IR vie -emit-llvm option and use `opt` tool to invoke any LLVM optimization passes.

Comment: A have a couple of questions:
Where I can find the clang optimisation flags?
What should I use? clang's flags or LLVM's passes?
Are the clang's flags implemented by using the LLVM's passes?

Comment: Just to note: you can in fact use something like `clang -cc1 -backend-option -instcombine` to set LLVM passes from clang, though using `opt` may well be a better option.

Answer (score 2):

as @Anton has mentioned above, these Compiler passes are meant to be used with llvm-opt not the clang, clang only supports the standard optimization level -O[X]. However if you would like to use your compiler flags. i.e. "-instcombine", first you have to add the option -emit-llvm while using the clang.

Some comments and examples:

1. The list of the LLVM-opt could be found [Here!](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html)
2. Here is a short example of using the LLVM-opt:

`clang -S -emit-llvm foo.c -lm`
`opt ${<MY_DESIRED_COMPILER_FLAGS>} -S -o foo_OPTIMIZED.ll foo.ll`

`clang foo_OPTIMIZED.ll -lm`

Now, if you take a `diff` of the  both versions of `LLVM-IR` or `.ll` files, you can see the differences.

3. OPTing a whole project

For that matter, you should put these commands in loop and apply the opt on each of every files you need

OR

Write a makefile that does this for you.

OR

Create your own pass consisting of your desired passes and include them as a .so file. More Info [Here!](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2011-September/043439.html)

Hope that helps.