# Disable optimizations from CLANG command line

Tags: optimization, clang

I would like to individually disable the command line options which `-O2` adds over `-O1` in Clang (with the LLVM backend)

I was able to identify which flags `-O2` enables over `-O1` using on this post: [Clang optimization levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548023/clang-optimization-levels)

Flags `-O2` adds: `-inline -mldst-motion -gvn -globaldce -constmerge -slp-vectorizer -elim-avail-extern`

How do I disable those flags individually?

(`-disable-slp-vectorized` worked but what about flags like `-gvn -globaldce`? I haven't been able to find a way to disable them.)

Comment: Can't you just use `-O1`? Also, AFAIK, some optimizations are built in the compiler and can't be disabled.

Comment: I don't think you can. Easiest option is using -O1 and then adding the flags you actually need, AFAIK.

Comment: I tried the other way around as well, but I don't have the confidence that they were actually enabled. I tried doing that using `-mllvm -pass-remarks=gvn`