# Clang adds noinline attribute to all functions when emitting LLVM IR

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

Consider the following simple function:

```
int foo() { return 42; }
```

Compiling this to LLVM via `clang -emit-llvm -S foo.cpp` produces the following module:

```
; ModuleID = 'foo.cpp'
source_filename = "foo.cpp"
target datalayout = "e-m:o-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-apple-macosx10.13.0"

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind ssp uwtable
define i32 @_Z3foov() #0 {
  ret i32 42
}

attributes #0 = { noinline nounwind ssp uwtable "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-jump-tables"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="penryn" "target-features"="+cx16,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+sse3,+sse4.1,+ssse3,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0}
!llvm.ident = !{!1}

!0 = !{i32 1, !"PIC Level", i32 2}
!1 = !{!"Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)"}
```

Why is the `foo` function declared as `noinline`? The flag is not added if an optimization level (other than `-O0`) is specified, but I would like to avoid that.

Is there another way / flag?

Comment: Makes sense to me that, for an unoptimized build (that needs to be debugable), functions are not inlined. Why do you want it otherwise?

Comment: I want to modify / analyze it further with an external tool (and hence need it to be unoptimized), but want to be able to pass the modified module to `opt` later and have it optimized then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With -O0, you can't enable inlining globally, judging from Clang's source code
(`Frontend\CompilerInvocation.cpp`):

```
// At O0 we want to fully disable inlining outside of cases marked with
// 'alwaysinline' that are required for correctness.
Opts.setInlining((Opts.OptimizationLevel == 0)
                  ? CodeGenOptions::OnlyAlwaysInlining
                  : CodeGenOptions::NormalInlining);
```

Depending on your requirements, you may:

- Use `-O1`, which is the closest to `-O0`.
- Use `-O1` in conjuction with disabling of optimization flags that it enables. See the following answer for optimization flags enabled with `-O1`:  [Clang optimization levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548023/clang-optimization-levels)
- Apply `always_inline` attribute selectively on functions that should be inlined.
  For example: `int __attribute__((always_inline)) foo() { return 42; }`