# What compiler options does `-O2` enable in clang?

Tags: c, optimization, clang, compiler-optimization

We've found that `-O2` breaks a program, and we would like to find out which optimization option actually causes the problem, so we can produce a bug report.

Is there an equivalent list of options that `-O2` enables in Clang (for C)?  I checked [the docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html) but it just says *"-O2 Moderate level of optimization which enables most optimizations."*

But, *which* optimizations?

Comment: Related: [Clang optimization levels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15548023/11082165)

Comment: If you can produce a [mre] for the suspected bug you found, consider posting it as a question on this site. We even have a tag for it: [\[compiler-bug\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler-bug). There's some smart folks on this site that may be able to offer some useful info for the report / find an existing report / sniff out some hidden UB.

Comment: *We've found that -O2 breaks a program* It's remotely possible you've triggered a bug in clang, but it's far more likely in my experience that your program is what's broken; something like relying on undefined behavior acting in a particular way that changes at a higher optimization level, for example.

Comment: @Shawn, that's my experience too.  Another developer is working on it, so if he can shrink the scope down maybe we can ask a codereview or compiler bug question.

Comment: @Brian61354270, thanks for the hint.  I was told by the other developer that _"Looks like the bug was in my code - an inline function that had to be declared static."_.  Not sure why an non-static inline would break `-O2` so maybe it would be a good SE question.  Unfortunately I don't have the details or I'd pose one.

Answer (score 4):

You can see what optimizations that were used, which is not necessarily the same as which ones that where enabled, but it might be close enough.

```
clang -Xclang -ftime-report=per-pass
```

Answer (score 2):

> But, which optimizations?

You'll have to look at the exact source and version of Clang you are using to figure out the list. It can also change between patch releases.

Which is to say: knowing in the *exact* list is pretty useless.